# White dirt in jatoba fretboard

Tags: guitar, maintenance, fretboard, lutherie

My brand new JemJR has weird white dust inside wood. I already tried to clean it using some paper and water. It looked perfect right after cleaning it, but it returned once the fretboard was dry.

What is it? How could I remove it?

[image: white dirt]

[image: white dirt]

Answer (score 1):

This was answered on the [Woodworking stack: getting slurry out of wood grains](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/5505/getting-sanded-poly-slurry-out-of-wood-grains)

It's liquified sanding dust. Fine-grit paper creates tiny particles which mixed with the finish and dried into the grain.